# Javascript e4x engine with unit testing ?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, e4x

All,

I am looking for server side javascript engine which supports e4x too and also unit testing framework for the same to intergrate with CI (hudson).

One option i thought is http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/ , but couldn't get a good testing framework.

Requirements -

1. serverside Javascript engine with e4x support.
2. Unit testing framework for the same.

Any suggestions ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[SpiderMonkey](http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/) runs server-side and supports E4x, while [Jasmine](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/) claims to be independent from the browser, DOM or other frameworks. Not sure how well it integrates with Hudson or if it has any support for unit-testing E4x.